# Assigning a symbol for footnote in shade box

Tags: footnotes

After looking at this [Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers) I am still wondering how can I change the footnote in a shade box. The code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{boxedlaw}[1]
  {\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}{#1‎}‎}
  {\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\begin{center}\shadowbox{\TheSbox}\end{center}}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{boxedlaw}{\textwidth}
This is just a simple text to fill in the line. You notice that if I put a footnote here
\footnote{This is the foot note}
the shape or numbering used would be out of my control.How can I control that?
 \end{boxedlaw}

 \end{document}
```

the result would be a footnote with letter "a" in my texLive.

> How can I change it to an ordinary number footnote and specially how can I make it continue from the last footnote? {I mean, if I have footnote number 2 as the last footnote, it show me the footnote number 3 and the other footnotes after it continue as usual.

I took a look at this [Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/footnotes-in-tables) but doesn't look promising.

Comment: See also: [Can I get a normal footnote in a minipage environement in LaTeX? How?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274/can-i-get-a-normal-footnote-in-a-minipage-environement-in-latex-how) and [\footnotemark and \footnotetext in minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/956/footnotemark-and-footnotetext-in-minipage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minipages have its own counter

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\newenvironment{boxedlaw}[1]
  {\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}{#1‎}‎\setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\begin{center}\shadowbox{\TheSbox}
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}\end{center}}

\renewcommand*\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

foo\footnote{foo}

\begin{boxedlaw}{\textwidth}
This is just a simple text to fill in the line. You notice that if I put a footnote here
\footnote{This is the foot note}
the shape or numbering used would be out of my control.How can I control that?
 \end{boxedlaw}

bar\footnote{bar}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: How about continuing from the last footnote? Should I actually hardcode the number of the footnote and set the footnote counter after this box? Do we have any kind of box around text that the counter is as usual and does not need any extra command or at least with the help of command the footnote to be assumed as an ordinary one?

Comment: sorry, forgot it. I edit the code