# How to write a footnote in Tikz poster class?

Tags: footnotes, tikzposter

I am getting problem in adding a footnote in tikz poster class?

Comment: there's no way to help you, as long your question stays like this. please provide more information, a MWE, and be more precise about your problem. thank you

Answer (score 1):

A bit fiddly, but this seems to work. You need to manually keep track of which text goes with which footnote though.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\let\thempfootnote\thefootnote%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/956/footnotemark-and-footnotetext-in-minipage#959
\newcommand\printfootnote[1]{% to get different numbers for different footnotes
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}%
\footnotetext{#1}}
\begin{document}
\block{Foo}{Lorem\footnotemark{} dolor}% use \footnotemark to make the number
\block{bar}{Sit\footnotemark{} consectetur }


% add the nootnotes in a node
\node [text width=10cm,above right] at (bottomleft) {% the bottomleft coordinate is defined by the class
\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
\printfootnote{ipsum} % ipsum is the text of the footnote
\printfootnote{amet}
};
\end{document}
```