# How to auto increment arabic mpfootnote numbers?

Tags: footnotes, minipage

If I follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/959/112503) answer, to switch the mpfootnotemark style from alpha to arabic, the mpfootnotemarks' values are not auto incremented any more.

That's what I've done:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
Outer-Sentence One.\footnote{}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \newcounter{tmpMpFnCnt}
  \setcounter{tmpMpFnCnt}{\value{footnote}}%<- store footnote counter
  \setcounter{mpfootnote}{10}

  %uncommenting the following line enables arabic mpfootnotemarks, but disables
  %the auto incrementation:
  %\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\thefootnote}

  MP-Sentence one.\footnote{1st mp-footnote's content},

  MP-Sentence two.\footnote{2nd mp-footnote's content}

  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{tmpMpFnCnt}}%<- reset footnote counter
\end{minipage}

\vspace{3cm}

Outer-Sentence two.\footnote{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got it. The redefinition of `\thempfootnote` was wrong. That works for me:

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
```

BTW: Storing and restoring the outer footnote's value is redundant.